# Replace whole body widget with resultant data in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

when experimenting with flutter, I faced a problem in first page. I have my form widget in the body with raised button and gesture detector. While submitting form, I'm searching for the users and I could fetch data from db of type list model successfully. How can I list the users results, in listview builder replacing the whole form widget?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a `StatefulWidget`, once your data changes, you call `setState` and your `build` function will be called again, then you can change what's built, adding the new data.

Remember a `build` function just have to return a `Widget` so you can place all the decision making logic you want there, to have a different screen.

Or you could navigate to a new screen, which shows this new information, that's up to you.